# "No boot device available" after running Ubuntu boot repair utility

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows

need your help:

1. after setting up dual boot (Windows & Ubuntu) on Dell PC, Grub did not load on startup (it would go straight to Windows)
2. In an attempt to fix this, I ran the Ubuntu boot repair utility
3. Now, on startup, i get message: "No boot device available" - and unable to boot either Windows or Ubuntu.
4. in boot menu, neither Windows nor Ubuntu are listed as options

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/